# iteration through outlook appointments

Tags: outlook

I know how to iterate through non-recurring appointments in Outlook.

My question is, how to I iterate through Outlook appointments including the recurring appointments?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question, not sure why the downvote.  Grammar and spelling are bad but I'm guessing he's not a native speaker.  Editing for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using 3rd party libraries, I'd suggest using "Redemption" library (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). This library has useful **RDOFolder2** interface with **GetActivitiesForTimeRange** method.

Here you can find more information about usage of this interface:
(http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdofolder.htm)

If you don't want to use 3rd party library and need to stick to Outlook API, the trick is to set **IncludeRecurrences** flag to true before iterating appointments. The following article should provide enough information on how to do that: 
(http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=30)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to use third party tools. There is the option IncludeRecurrences which takes care of this:

```
    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Set oItems = MyFolder.Items

' Restrict Date
strFilter = "[Start] >= " + "'"  + ourStart + "'"
Set oItems = oItems.Restrict(strFilter)

strFilter = "[End] <= " + "'"  + ourEnd + "'"
Set oItems = oItems.Restrict(strFilter)

' Restrict Category
strFilter = "[Categories] = " + "'"  + ourCategory + "'"
Set oItems = oItems.Restrict(strFilter)

oItems.Sort "[Start]"

' We want recurring, too (http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/get-recurring-appointment-dates-vba-t799214.html)
oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
```